# Proof of an equation involving nabla

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\mathbf r = x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j+z\mathbf k$

and $r = |\mathbf r|$.

If $f$ is a differentiable function of one variable show that:

$$ \nabla (f(r)\mathbf r) = r f'(r)+3f(r)$$

I get as far as this:

$$ \nabla (f(r)\mathbf r) = f'(r) \mathbf r + f(r)(\nabla\mathbf r) = \cdots + 3f(r)$$

I don't know how to find the $\cdots$ part. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: IMHO this can't be right, since on the lhs is a vector and on the rhs a scalar.

Comment: Do you mean the result should be $(rf'+3)\hat r$, where $\hat r$ is the radial unit vector?

Comment: The result should be as indicated by ∇(f(r)r)=rf′(r)+3f(r)

Comment: That cannot be the case.  The gradient maps scalar fields into vector fields.  The divergence operator maps vectors into scalars.  I believe that you want the divergence of the product of $f(r)$ with the position vector.

Comment: How would the " divergence of the product of f(r) with the position vector" look in math?

Comment: $\nabla \cdot (f(r)\mathbf r)$

Comment: Do you really want to compute the gradient of a vector-valued function? Maybe you mean ${\rm div}\bigl(f(r)\>{\bf r}\bigr)$.

Comment: (+1) for the question 7 years later

Answer (score 1):

Note that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, hence 
$$ \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac 1{2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \cdot 2x = \frac{x}r $$
$\partial_y r$ and $\partial_z r$ are computed analogously. Hence the gradient of $\mathbf r \mapsto r$ is given by $\nabla r = \frac{\mathbf r}{r}$. Therefore 
$$ \nabla \cdot \bigl(f(r)\def\r{\mathbf r}\r\bigr) 
  = f'(r)\nabla r \cdot \r + f(r) \nabla\cdot \r = f'(r) \cdot \frac{\r}r\cdot \r + 3f(r) = rf'(r) + 3f(r). $$

Comment: please see my comment above.

Comment: @Karl Thx, corrected.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @martini I am assuming that the $\nabla r$ arises from the fact that we use the chain rule when taking the derivative of $f$. Is it correct to assume that?

Comment: Right, @Nash, it's the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla \cdot (f(r)\mathbf r)=f(r)\nabla \cdot (\mathbf r)+\mathbf r \cdot \nabla (f(r))$ by the product rule for differentiation.  The first term is $3f(r)$; this is trivial since $\mathbf r = \hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz$.  The second term is $$\mathbf r \cdot \nabla (f(r))=\mathbf r \cdot[f'(r)\nabla(r)]=\mathbf r \cdot[f'(r)\hat r]=rf'(r)$$where the chain rule was used.  Putting it all together then, we obtain$$\nabla \cdot (f(r)\mathbf r)=3f(r)+rf'(r)$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my chain rule question! :)

Comment: My pleasure Nash.  Is your class physics, math, or engineering?

Comment: It is called Numerical Analysis 2 (multiple variable calculus mixed with multiple variable numerical analysis). :)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?